# MySQL - Load Data Infile with filename

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load a file using the command below:

```
'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'H://test-Project//SampleFiles//Employee.csv' 
IGNORE INTO Table     Employee_Tbl. 
(emp_code,emp_name,emp_pi_id);
```

One of the columns in the table is the file name. THe file content of 'Employee.csv' does not consist of the 'file name' explicitly. And I need is the value 'Employee.csv' to be populated into this table along with insert of the data rows from the file. Any thoughts as to how I can do this? Would greatly appreciate your help.
thanks

Comment: Am I right in assuming you want to: `LOAD DATA INFILE '...file...' IGNORE INTO TABLE table(fields,...) SET filename='Employees.csv';`?

Comment: Yes, That's correct Robert. However, how do I set that in an automated manner whereby just the file name alone gets populated without the entire path. Just so, the filename can change